# Notation for a partially evaluated $n$ dimensional function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation

I can’t seem to find the right phrasing to google this question. Suppose I have function $$f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$
you might denote the evaluation of $f$ at point $(x,y)$ as $f(x,y)$. For any $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, you can make a function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, y\mapsto f(x_0,y)$.

Is there any standard notation for this function $g$ (which refers to $f$ and $x_0$ in some way)?

*(Note: I want to use this notation (above) to turn a function with $n$ variables mapping into a ($n$-$m$) dimensional codomain, the function $f$ above is just an example)*

Comment: $g=f(x_0,\cdot).$

Comment: To expand on Anne's comment, yes, the usual notation for this construction is to use a centered dot for the "free" argument.

Comment: Could this notation deal with the case when there are $n$ variables and $x_0$ is the $m$th variable? This may be too complicated to have a general notation though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it is valid to use the notation $g= f(x_0,\cdot)$. However, you are correct that this isn't generally practical when we are dealing with many variables. Another (in my opinion better) way to denote a function like $g$ is as follows.

Let's consider the example some function $f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \Omega$ where $\Omega$ could be anything, it doesn't really matter. Then we can define the functions $f_{x_0} := f(x_0, y, z)$ and $f_{y_0} := f(x, y_0, z)$ and $f_{z_0} := f(x, y, z_0)$. This allows you to hold one variable constant much more easily when you are dealing with functions of an arbitrary number of variables (note that $x_0, y_0, z_0$ are all held constant and are not variables in the above functions).

Another example to generalise the above would be to consider a function $h: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \Omega$ and define

$$h_{x_{i_0}} := h(x_1, ... x_{i_0} . . . x_n)$$

This allows you to take any function with a finite dimensional domain and define a new function from this where we hold one of the variables in the domain constant (as before, $x_{i_0}$ is held constant in the above example and so it is not a variable).

As mentioned in the comments, there is some ambiguity regarding this notation when it is being evaluated at a specific value. The common workaround (that I am not personally a fan of) is when dealing with a function of two variables to use the alternative notation of $f_{x_0}$ and $f^{y_0}$. However, the reason that I am not a fan of this notation is that it can be mistaken for being an exponent and also does not generalise to a function of more variables very well.

The notation that I have always preferred is to still denote the function as $h_{x_{i_0}}(x_1 . . . x_n)$ in this way, however, when we are evaluating at a specific value of $x_{i_0}$, we use the less common (but much clearer) notation of $h_{[x_{i_0} = \space n]}$ for some fixed value $n$.

**Alternatives**

For completeness, here are some other ways to address your concern.

> 1. We can use evaluation notation. Where we define a new function $g$ such that:
>    $$g_{(i,\alpha )} := f(x_1 \space . . . \space  x_{(i-1)}, \space \alpha , \space x_{(i+1)} . . . x_n )  $$
>    Here the i$^{th}$ variable is replaced with the constant $\alpha$.

> 2. You can use the "restriction" notation $f\space |_{(x_i = 5)}$. This can become quite cumbersome and so you can define this as a new function. However, if you do this then it transposes into an equivalent definition of the function $g$ in ($1$).

Ultimately, I feel as though there are shortcomings to both of these approaches as it becomes notationally difficult to define $n$ different functions that are each responsible for fixing one of the $n$ variables in the domain.

Therefore, the notation that I would recommend would still be that which I recommended in the original answer. However, these are all valid alternatives and have all been used before in this context.

Comment: The subscript notation reasonable, but I don't like that in your suggestion the symbol used for dummy variables has a meaning. Your final suggestion is on the right track for solving my problems though.

Comment: $f_{x_0}$ and $f_{y_0}$ are different functions as you defined them, which cannot be. For example I can choose $x_0=5$ and $f_5$ no longer shows which variable is evaluated at 5.

Comment: There are two ways in which this ambiguity is cleared up. If you are dealing with two variables then $f_{x_0}$ and $f^{y_0}$ are common. However, I have never been a fan of this notation as it doesn’t generalise very easily. And more importantly, it looks like an exponent @ReinTurtle

Comment: What I would suggest instead is the (admittedly less common) notation of $f_{[x_{i_0}=5]}$. It’s not perfect, but is still succinct and there is little ambiguity about what else this could mean @ReinTurtle

Comment: I've added two alternative pieces of notation too. Let me know if that clarifies your issue @ReinTurtle

Comment: I agree that both ways you talk about (and probably any short notation without strict conventions) has its problems. Thanks for the help, this is certainly more than enough inspiration to find my preferred notation.